# ASP.NET MVC 5 Model for Forms With DropDown Menus and DatePicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new with ASP.NET MVC. I need help in developing a model for a form that has 3 drop down menu (drop-down 1. Picks number of people to party 2.Picks Time of arrival (options are like thus 12:00,12:30,1:00,1:30 and so on) 3. Picks Venue of party ) and finally a data picker. I'm not sure what the best way is in developing a model for such a view. Where should the drop down menu options reside, the model or the controller, how can I use an Enum for all the drop down menus? I've seen several questions but non have a clear cut way of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model with Id columns for the dropdown fields
you can use the `ienumerable` select list to populate the values of the dropdown, using enums (good approach if those values dont change). in the View binding to the dropdown, you have to fill the `ienumerable` any ways from the controller action before displaying the view.

Points to begin